# Question about optimize pandas script removing for loop (iterrows, zip, ...)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am searching a way to speed up my script in pandas dataframe.

To Understand the situation i will exemplify the two datasets that are involved in the script.

First we have the "entrydata", that is a list of things that we bought. that has a column called "date", a column called "id" and a column called "value" like the table above:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Id</th> 
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/01/2017</td>
    <td>111</td> 
    <td>58.4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/01/2017</td>
    <td>222</td> 
    <td>120.7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02/18/2017</td>
    <td>111</td> 
    <td>59.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02/18/2017</td>
    <td>222</td> 
    <td>130.8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>04/13/2017</td>
    <td>111</td> 
    <td>59.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>04/13/2017</td>
    <td>222</td> 
    <td>130.8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The other data we have is the "outdata", that is a list of things that we sell, we have a column called "date", a column called "id" and a column called "value" like the table above:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Id</th> 
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/03/2017</td>
    <td>111</td> 
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/03/2017</td>
    <td>111</td> 
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/03/2017</td>
    <td>111</td> 
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/03/2017</td>
    <td>222</td> 
    <td>122</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>01/03/2017</td>
    <td>222</td> 
    <td>122</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02/25/2017</td>
    <td>222</td> 
    <td>122</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02/25/2017</td>
    <td>111</td> 
    <td>70</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>02/25/2017</td>
    <td>222</td> 
    <td>135</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With those datasets, i wrote a script that used a for loop like the code above:

```
for row in tqdm(zip(dbOut["Date"],dbOut["Id"],dbOut["Value"])):
    dateOut = row[0]
    idOut = row[1]
    valueOut = row[2]

    #get all entry rows that have idOut id
    dbSample = dbEntry.loc[dbEntry["Id"] == idOut]

    #now do the mean of the column Value
    result = dbSample["Value"].mean()

    #append to an array created before the loop
    valuefinal.append(result)

#out of loop we put it in the outdata dataFrame in a new column
dbOut["FinalValue"] = valuefinal
```

Basically, these is what the script do. There are more columns in entry and out frames, but with theses sample i think i resumed what is going on.

These code works fine in terms of result, but i would like to speed it up. First the code was written with the loop using iterrows. Searching for a way to speed up, i saw that iterrows was a bad choice. So i changed to itertuples, and than to the zip function.

All that works in terms of result, but the time of iterations didn't change a lot. i am speaking of about 300 iterations/second.

Than i did a change in part of the code using vectorization, and depending on the entrydata, i got a increase to 600 to 1200iterations/second.

some part of the code was able to be vectorized, but the other one could not! The part that could be vectorized was the one that make simple subtraction using two others columns.

The part that used a reduced dataframe with a specific Id i could not vectorize, because it was showing the following error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

The code i tried to vectorize i simple removed from the loop and made the changes that was needed. Here is the original code inside the loop:

```
result = dbSample["Value"].mean
```

And here is the code i tried to vectorize removing the loop:

```
dbOut["FinalValue"] = dbEntry.loc[dbEntry["Id"] == dbOut["Id"]]["Value"].mean()
```

Finally, to the question. Can i make these kind of vectorization with specific part of a dataframe (entryData)? Any suggestions to make the code runs faster? Like 3000iterations/second?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: after seeing your code i think this will work... outdata['FinalValue'] = outdata.apply(lambda x: entrydata[entrydata['Id'] == x.Id]['Value'].mean(), axis=1)

Comment: There is absolutely no use in lambda as far as I understood the question.

Comment: The problem I see in these line: outdata['FinalValue'] = outdata.apply(lambda x: entrydata[entrydata['Id'] == x.Id]['Value'].mean(), axis=1); is, where is the dbOut["Id"] info that will be used to find in the entry data?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the apply function that works well with only one value to return, when I use all the code that i need, I get an error.

So, thinking here, i did a reduction in the dbOut, before running in the zip loop. Instead of 75000 rows of dbOut, I removed the duplicates, leaving only each 1 of the Id's column, and saved it in a dbOut2, which i apllied in the zip loop. The efficieny is that now i need to run only 5000 rows, making things faster!

Now, I tried to pass the information from the dbOut2 to de dbOut. I used np.where, that i read is a very fast way:

```
dbOut["FinalValue"] = np.where(dbOut("ID") == dbOut2("ID"), dbOut2("Value"),0)
```

That line is supposed to work, but I didn't succeed. Any advices on how to properly put the info i had in dbOut2 (5000 rows) into dbOut (75000 rows)?

Thanks Again!